# Replace a field with maximum of it's attribute values based on values repeated on another field's attribute values using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, attribute-table, cursor, features, maximum

So I have performed Spatial Join between a point and line feature class. Now for each point there are several lines. What I want is the maximum count of line features as an attribute value in the "Count" field based on "label" field same attribute values. [image]

I have thought of few ways to do it but isn't working exactly. I can also add a new field and write the maximum of those "Count" values there.

Here I was trying to convert it into a numpy array and then calculate the maximum.

```
   '''try:
        arr_label_count= arcpy.da.FeatureClassToNumPyArray("SPATIAL_JOIN_OUTPUT_Splice_Closures_Fibre_Drop_copy",
                                                                     ["label", "Count"], skip_nulls=True)
        arcpy.AddMessage(arr_label_count)
    except Exception as e:
        arcpy.AddMessage("Issue in arr_label_count...: " + str(e))

    try:
        arr_label= arcpy.da.FeatureClassToNumPyArray("SPATIAL_JOIN_OUTPUT_Splice_Closures_Fibre_Drop_copy",
                                                                     ["label"], skip_nulls=True)
        arcpy.AddMessage(arr_label)
        filtered_arr_label = self.remove_duplicates(arr_label)
        # arcpy.AddMessage(filtered_arr_label)
    except Exception as e:
        arcpy.AddMessage("Issue in arr_label_count...: " + str(e))'''
```

Here is an image of how the array looks -
[image]

Comment: @BERA i want the results in that field or in a new field where it will simply match the labels and write the maximum values from "Count" for that label. I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set your COUNT field to the largest value per Label you can list the values, sort by value, and store in a dictionary. Then update/calculate using da.UpdateCursor:

```
import arcpy

fc = r'C:\GIS\ArcMap_default_folder\Default.gdb\my_sample'

group_field = 'KKOD' #In your case Label
value_field = 'VAL' #In your case Count

vals = [i for i in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, [group_field, value_field])]
vals.sort(key=lambda x: x[1]) #Sort the values by value field so largest value is last
maxval_per_group = {i[0]:i[1] for i in vals} #Create a dictionary with group as key and last=largest value as value

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, [group_field, value_field]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0] in maxval_per_group:
            row[1] = maxval_per_group[row[0]]
            cursor.updateRow(row)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks will surely try this out.